# Recover complex function from its real part

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The real part of $z=x+yi$ is given as $\Re f(z) = x^2-y^2+xy$. Therefore I have
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
G_x = 2x+y \\ 
G_y = -2y + x
\end{array}
\right.
$$
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
G_{xx} = 2 \\ 
G_{yy} = -2
\end{array}
\right.
$$
$G_{xx} + G_{yy} = 0$, therefore the function is harmonic.

Next step is
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
v_y = G_x = 2x+y \\ 
v_x = -G_y = 2y-x 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

To find the actual $v$, I integrate $v_y$ with respect to $y$:
$$
v = \int_{y_0}^y (2x + \tau)d\tau + C(x) = 2\int_{y_0}^y xd\tau + \int_{y_0}^y \tau d\tau  +C(x) = 2x\tau \Big|_{y_0}^y + {\frac{\tau^2}{2}}\Big|_{y_0}^y + C(x) = 2x(y-y_0) + {\frac{y^2}{2}} - {\frac{y_0^2}{2}}  +C(x)
$$

Let's calculate $v_x$:
$$
v_x = 2x(y=y_0)_x + ({\frac{y^2}{2}} - {\frac{y_0^2}{2}})\prime + C\prime (x)$$
$$2(y-y_0) + y-y_0 + C\prime (x) = 2y -x$$
$$3y-3y_0+C\prime (x) = 2y-x$$
$$y-3y_0+C\prime (x)=-x$$
$$C\prime (x) = 3y_0-y-x$$
To find $C(x)$, we must integrate $C\prime (x)$:
$$C(x) = \int_{x_0}^x (3y_0-y-\tau)d\tau = 3\int_{x_0}^x y_0d\tau - \int_{x_0}^x yd\tau - \int_{x_0}^x \tau d\tau = 3y_0\tau \Big|_{x_0}^x - y\tau \Big|_{x_0}^x - {\frac{\tau^2}{2}}\Big|_{x_0}^x = 3y_0(x-x_0) - y(x-x_0) - {\frac{x^2}{2}} + {\frac{x_0^2}{2}} = 3xy_0 - 3x_0y_0 - yx + yx_0 - {\frac{x^2}{2}} + {\frac{x_0^2}{2}}$$

Now we can have the full $v$:
$$v = 2xy - 2xy_0 + {\frac{y^2}{2}} - {\frac{y_0^2}{2}} + 3xy_0 - 3x_0y_0 - yx + yx_0 - {\frac{x^2}{2}} + {\frac{x_0^2}{2}}$$

I'm really confused here. Were all my previous steps right? How do I get the final answer. By the way, it is
$$
f(z) = (1-{\frac{i}{2}})z^2 + iC
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but why have you done it so long. Consider
$$v=\int v_y\ dy=2xy+\frac12y^2+h(x)+C$$
then 
$$v_x=2y+h'(x)=2y-x$$
and $h(x)=-\dfrac12x^2$. Finally 
$$f(z)=u+iv=(x^2-y^2+xy)-i\dfrac{1}{2}(x^2-y^2-4xy)+iC=(1-\frac12i)z^2+iC$$